# Dask : parallel computing not effective

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to use Dask but I have a lot of problem to achieve my aim.

My use case is to calculate features on timeseries with Dask `map_partitions`. I so organize my code to read all my timeseries (123000 little .parquet files) in a Dask Dataframe.
To optimize the calculation, I made some repartitions and I create Dask `LocalCluster` with 10 CPUs (my machine has got 12 CPUs).
On each partition, I apply a personal function with `map_repartions` to calcule all my features.
Few moments after the begining of the calculation, Dask become very slow and only 3 processes (CPUs) maximum are used until the moment when I hace the message `KilledWorker`.

To do not have problem with Python mutithreading (GIL), I force 1 thread per process.

Hereunder my simplified code :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=10, processes=True, threads_per_worker=1)
    client = Client(cluster)

    logger.info(f'Cluster Dask: {cluster}')
    logger.info(f'Cluster Dask dashboard: {cluster.dashboard_link}')

    dask_data = dd.read_parquet(ROOT_PATH + r"\*\data.parquet",
                                columns=VAR_LIST,
                                engine='pyarrow',
                                ignore_metadata_file=False) \
        .repartition(npartitions=100) \
        .persist()

    # extract_tsfresh_features is the function making the features calculation
    dask_df_features = dask_data.map_partitions(extract_tsfresh_features,
                                                column_id=VAR_ID,
                                                column_sort=VAR_SORT,
                                                settings=config_tsfresh_extractor)

    # OUTPUT is the path to wuite the result .parquet file
    dask_df_features.to_parquet(OUTPUT,
                                engine="pyarrow",
                                append=False)

    client.close()
    cluster.close()

    logger.info('Process end.')
```

I don't understand what' really append.

If you have some advices, I'm OK !!!

Regards.

Rémy

**Edit 23/03/29 :** I try to follow the advice of Dask documentation by making repartions of 100MB with `.repartition(partition_size="100MB")` and I have exactly the same problem.
Moreover, too manage better the memory, I adjust all my 10 workers with a memory limit of 4GB (I have a laptop with 64GB).
After repartition, my 123000 files are repartited in 3 partitions, and after a long time of calculation, the 3 workers died ...

Comment: You call `.persist()` on your dataframe. Are you sure you have enough resources to store all of it in memory at once? What is the total data size (on disk, and estimate in memory) ?

Comment: Yes, in total, all my _.parquet_ files weight 3,7GB in memory (and my laptop has got at least, 40GB free). As I can read on the net, the Dask "unmanaged memory" is a big problem on Windows (my case). For Linux and MacOS, there is some easy solutions to trim manually or automatically the memory (C malloc librairy).

Comment: OK, I found a good set of parameters to achieve the calculation. With `npartitions=50` and 2 threads per processus, I can go to the end of the calculation. And this, even if the rates of "unmanaged" worker memories are very high. I'm going to test my code with Linux to compare the behavior.

Comment: Do you have some knowledges for how determine the good number of repartition with Dask ?

Comment: It can be tricky. You may wish to repartition and write to a new dataset before starting the next phase of calculations.

Comment: By looking for in the code of some librairies using Dask , I dicover that TSFRESH have a empirical tweak for a LocalCulster.